# CartThrob: Discount Plug-In - Buy X Get Y not working

Tags: cartthrob

I've recently installed the following CartThrob discount plug-in and it's not working.  I can't get it to add the free product "Y" to the Cart.

**Buy X Get Y**
https://github.com/CartThrob/cartthrob-discounts-buy_x_get_y

My discount settings...
[image]

I'm running EE Version 2.7 and CT 2.5.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Darren

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it actually will add the free item automatically to the cart. In fact I'm pretty sure that's not what the plugin is meant to do.

If you add the free item manually then you should see that it gets discounted from the total. I think that's all the plugin does.

You may need to create a 'package' product that contains the 2 items.

Comment: Hi Foamcow - thanks for commenting and qualifying how the plug-in works.  The plugin only seems to work though if you add two of the same product.  It doesn't seem to work if you add different Products (even though they are specified - one as X and the other as Y).  Any idea?